# Laravel 5 How to make files as downloadable in asset folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following  [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) tutorial to upload files
Uploading is fine, but I want to create a link to download files.
I am doing

```
$contents = Storage::get($path);
echo '<a href="'.$contents.'">Thing</a>';
```

but it is echoing file content. What I want is link to file download.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add download attribute  '<a href="'.$contents.'" download>Thing</a>';

Comment: Have you created a symbolic link from public to storage using `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: already did       php artisan storage:link   
@linktoahref

Comment: Then you could use the `asset()` helper method `'<a href="'. asset($path).'">`

Comment: added download attribute but it is showing content of file in url.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this from a controller like this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `download` attribute

```
$path="your path"
echo '<a href="'.$path.'" download>Thing</a>';
```

but i recommend to use function to download like this

```
public function download()
{

    $file= "file_Path";

    $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/png',
            );

    return Response::download($file, 'yourfile.png', $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the download attribute to your element

```
echo '<a href="'.$contents.'" download>Thing</a>';
```

Following this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem),

> The `get` method may be used to retrieve the contents of a file. The raw string contents of the file will be returned by the method.

So instead of using `get` method use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset) helper method to retrieve the url to the file.

```
echo '<a href="'. asset($path) .'">Thing</a>';
```

Comment: I am already doing that but when I go to the url

It says "
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
"

the url is in the format:
http://localhost/project/public/storage/sku/YaKn2dahPPizdpLFtQuADsdejaiz30Zt2sCM4Mvg.txt

location of the file is : storage/sku/YaKn2dahPPizdpLFtQuADsdejaiz30Zt2sCM4Mvg.txt

@linktoahref

Comment: I think I need to add public in my url?

Comment: Not needed if you have created the symbolic link from the public directory to the storage directory